# How to make a book on website?

Tags: pdf, tiff, epub

I am trying to figure out how to convert these documents (currently in .tiff) into a book like format so that it looks pretty much like this:

https://0-ebookcentral-proquest-com.ignacio.usfca.edu/lib/usflibrary-ebooks/reader.action?docID=5041697

or anything relatively similar that allows you to flip through the pages of a book. I want to know what I can look into, since I'm not sure where to even start.

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular programming problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: Do you know where I could post problems such as this?

Comment: Maybe the Chat Rooms or [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. I've asked a few questions at SR.SE, but there were not a lot of answers. I usually use DocBook when creating books and manuals, but I've never had to start with a TIFF. You will probably need to continue your research.

Answer (score 0):

I would just make the file into a PDF. PDFs let you 'flip' through the book by pressing the arrow keys (because it moves onto the next page). If you don't want to do that, you could always put the book into a HTML website, like how http://www.gutenberg.org does.
By the way, the link you have in you question requires a sign-in, so I can't tell exactly how you want to have your book.